# adding other files to haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Im writing app in haskell and I would like to export some functions and datatypes to other files and then be able to use them in my main file.

How to do this ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Wikibooks page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Modules) on Haskell modules would be a good starting point, or the [relevant section](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules) of Learn You a Haskell (especially the "Making our own modules" part).

Answer (score 5):

You could lay out your source code like so:

```
Main.hs
A/Module.hs
```

You need to specify in `A/Module.hs` which module it actually is; it has to be:

```
module A.Module where

...
```

In `Main.hs`, you import `A.Module`; all names are exported by default.

Comment: But in Haskell module names don't *have* to match file names in the same sense that a Java class `com.example.Service` *has* to be in `com/example/Service.java`. Individual compilers can establish conventional correspondences for the sake of convenience, but you could also tell GHC (for example) to find `MyModule` in `SomeRandomDirectory/NotMyModule.hs` if you really wanted to, and (more typically) your `Main` module doesn't have to live in a file named `Main.hs`.

Comment: That's true; you can break from convention if you want to. It's not uncommon to see Cabal project directories that have `src/A/Module.hs`.

The more sophisticated redirects that you suggest, I've never tried.